# Как распарсить строку в <T extends Number>?

Tags: java, строки

Есть метод:

```
private Executable numValidate(int num, By by, Comparator<Integer> comp) {
    return () -> {
        WebElement elem = chrome.findElement(by);
        if (isNull(elem)) {
            return false;
        }
        Integer value = Ints.tryParse(elem.getText());
        return !isNull(value) && comp.compare(num, value) > 0;
    };
}
```

Нужно сделать более универсальным для любых числовых типов:

```
private <N extends Number> Executable numValidate(N num, By by, Comparator<N> comp) {
    return () -> {
        WebElement elem = chrome.findElement(by);
        if (isNull(elem)) {
            return false;
        }
        ????Integer value = Ints.tryParse(elem.getText());????
        return !isNull(value) && comp.compare(num, value) > 0;
    };
}
```

Но как мне распарсить неизестный тип без `instanceof`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь вам поможет класс `NumberFormat`:

```java
Number number = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse("123.45");
```

Также можно указать локаль для форматов чисел:

```java
Number number1 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).parse("123.45");
Number number2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("ru")).parse("123,45");
```

Comment: хорошая метода, спасибо! А нельзя ли еще уточнить, каким образом число связано с локалью?

Comment: @Pavel, Десятичный разделитель зависит от локали.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант, можно просто перебрать все возможные типы:

```
....
Number value;
try {
    value = Integer.parseInt(string);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    try {
        value = Double.parseDouble(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        try {
            value = Long.parseLong(string);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            try {
                ...
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("....");
            }
        }
    }
}
....
```

Либо регуляркой узнать тип и парсить:

```
....
if (string.matches("-?\\d+")) {//тут при необходимости стоит предусмотреть количество знаков, чтобы распарсить Char/Integer/Long
    value = Integer.parseInt(string);
} else if (string.matches("-?\\d+\\.\\d+")) {
    value = Double.parseDouble(string);
} else......
```

Либо, если надо только сравнить строки, можно привести их к строкам и сравнить строковым компаратором.

P.S. Также в вашем примере дженерики не нужны.

```
private Executable numValidate(Number num, By by, Comparator<Number> comp) {
    return () -> {
        WebElement elem = chrome.findElement(by);
        if (isNull(elem)) {
            return false;
        }
        .....
        return !isNull(value) && comp.compare(num, value) > 0;
    };
}
```